# Where is SuperTux user folder located on latest Debian Bullseye Stable install?

Tags: linux, supertux

The title says it all: "Where is SuperTux user folder located on latest Debian Bullseye Stable install?"

The `.supertux2` folder is not located in my home directory, as many suggest. I haven't ever moved it, so it's got to be somewhere. Where does the official Debian Bullseye Stable package place it by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SuperTux user directory, as well as the configuration files, are stored in `~/.local/share/supertux2` for later versions, and in `~/.supertux2/` for earlier versions. I found mine in `~/.local/share/supertux2`, as I'm running version `v0.6.2`.

Source: https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux/wiki/Configuration-File